# Christoffel symbols of a surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I am looking for a way to write down the Christoffel symbols for a surface of revolution.

They are given by https://books.google.de/books?id=iwGjNhpkSeQC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=christoffel+symbols+surface+of+revolution&source=bl&ots=GscaSjskZ_&sig=r2K5ZOnAn22_ihu-0ERoijMKaqU&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Fx-eVLHTJsurPKK-gYAL&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=christoffel%20symbols%20surface%20of%20revolution&f=false

But I want to use them for a seminar, so I would rather prefer a compressed equation that contains the simplification of the symbols for this particular surface. Thus, I look for an equation that is simpler than the general definition, but something that is more straightforward than all these explicit representations.

Comment: What surface do you have in mind (the excerpt isn't visible in the U.S., by the way)? Is there a particular part of the computation that's giving you trouble?

Comment: a surface of revolution. (so one that is generated by a curve)

Comment: By "this particular surface" do you mean a general surface of revolution then?

Comment: @Travis yes, i do.

Comment: Your link does not lead to a page that is available to me. I will attempt to answer your question all the same, but bear with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x:p\mapsto(x^1(p),x^2(p))$ be the identity chart on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x:p\mapsto(x^1(p),x^2(p),x^3(p))$ be the identity chart on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose $\gamma:t\mapsto(\gamma^1(t),\gamma^2(t))$ is a (smooth) curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\neq0$ and $\gamma^1(t)\neq0$ for each $t$ in the domain of $\gamma$.

The image of the map $$f:U\to\mathbb{R}^3,~(t,\theta)\mapsto(\gamma^1(t)\cos\theta,\gamma^1(t)\sin\theta,\gamma^2(t))$$ is the surface of revolution from the curve $\gamma$.

The induced metric $\mathrm{g}=f^*\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^i\right)$ is \begin{align*}\sum_{i}f^*(\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^i) & =\sum_i\mathrm{d}f^i\otimes\mathrm{d}f^i \\ & =\sum_i\left((\partial_tf^i)^2\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t+(\partial_\theta f^i)^2\mathrm{d}\theta\otimes\mathrm{d}\theta\right. \\ & \hspace{4em}\left.+(\partial_tf^i)(\partial_\theta f^i)(\mathrm{d}\theta\otimes\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}\theta)\right) \\ & =\sum_i\left((\partial_tf^i)^2\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t+(\partial_\theta f^i)^2\mathrm{d}\theta\otimes\mathrm{d}\theta\right).\end{align*}

In this case, $\mathrm{g}=\!\!\left((\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\right)\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t+(\gamma^1)^2\mathrm{d}\theta\otimes\mathrm{d}\theta$. Using our coordinate formulae for the Christoffel symbols of the Levi-Civita connection, we get
\begin{align*}\Gamma_{11}^1 & =\frac{\partial_t\left((\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\right)}{2\left((\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\right)}=\frac{(\partial_t\gamma^1)\partial_t^2\gamma^1+(\partial_t\gamma^2)\partial_t^2\gamma^2}{\left((\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\right)}, \\
\Gamma_{11}^2 & =0, \\
\Gamma_{12}^1 & =\Gamma_{21}^1=0, \\
\Gamma_{12}^2 & =\Gamma_{21}^2=\frac{\partial_t\gamma^1}{\gamma^1}, \\
\Gamma_{22}^1 & =-\frac{\gamma^1\partial_t\gamma^1}{\left((\partial_t\gamma^1)^2+(\partial_t\gamma^2)^2\right)}, \\
\Gamma_{22}^2 & =0.\end{align*}

Comment: @TobiasHurth -- I'm mildly offended by that accusation. You told Travis you were looking for a solution for "a general surface of revolution." We both also commented that we cannot view the link you put in your question, so I went off of your comment. My answer is both "simpler" than for a generic surface of revolution and "more straightforward" than the general definition. What does this answer not accomplish?

Comment: @TobiasHurth I too am confused by your (also perplexingly) rude reply. I had planned to write a solution before Robin commented that he would do the same, and I had in mind more or less exactly what Robin wrote, and apparently exactly what was specified in the comments, namely, a straightforward derivation of the Christoffel symbols of a "general surface of revolution".

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow It may be worth commenting too that a few of the formulas simplify nicely in the special case that one takes $\gamma$ to be a unit-speed parameterization, namely we get $\Gamma_{11}^1 = 0$ and $\Gamma_{22}^1 = - \gamma^1 \partial_t \gamma^1$.